# Apply PDF Icon to Links - Caching Changes Extensions

Tags: css, wordpress, pdf, caching, attributes

wondering if there are any creative or advanced techniques for selecting a link for a downloadable PDF so we can add the icon, when caching changes the extension??

We would typically target the links by using: a[href$=".pdf"]

But unfortunately, it looks like our caching plugin (W3 Total Cache for WordPress) alters the extensions of the files so instead of '.pdf', they might now be something like '.pdf?bc07ce'. So, of course, our css cannot find them.

- Any wildcard or other elements I can add to the rule to just look for 'pdf' as part of the extension???

Thanks. We would prefer not to have to manually add a class or something to the link as the clients usually struggle figuring out how to do this or just forget. Wanted to make it a bit more 'foolproof' for them.

Answer (score 0):

You can add class `.pdf` to those links with JS, and in CSS make icon appear like that:

```
.pdf {
     background-color: #fff;
     background-image: url(images/pdficon_small.gif);
     background-position: bottom left;
     background-attachment: scroll;
     padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Find more in that discussion:  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pdf-icon-with-pdf-upload#post-754625

For JS if you use JQuery shall work something like this:

```
$('a[href*="pdf"]').addClass("pdf");
```

Comment: OK, thanks. I was hoping to do without JS, but am open. So would that JS find the characters 'pdf' ANYWHERE in a href, or is it only looking for it as part of the file extension? I would hope the term PDF wouldn't be entered without being for a PDF download, but you never know. Would a CSS wildcard like that do the same thing?

Comment: It will search for "pdf" letters in anywhere in the href. Yo better make dot before it, ad question mark after (do not forget about escaping) if it will appear always.

`$('a[href*="\\.pdf\\?"]').addClass("pdf");`

Or without `\\?`if it shows not always.